# Does it make sense to use ORDER BY clause when it comes to batch `start()` method

Tags: batch, querylocator

Could anyone explain more what
`Batches of records tend to execute in the order in which they’re received from the start method. However, the order in which batches of records execute depends on various factors. The order of execution isn’t guaranteed.` means?
Seems like we can't be sure of returned records order or not?

Comment: What difference order by makes here, ultimately batch will process all the records.

Answer (score 3):

No, that isn't quite what that section from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm#!) is saying.

If you `ORDER BY` your SOQL query in `start()`, the platform does not guarantee that the execution of *batches* will be in the same order as the records are in the query. Say for example you order by `Order_Num__c`, and your records have values from 1-10, and you are running with batch size 2. Your `execute()` method may be called with the batches

```
1,2
5,6
3,4
9,10
7,8
```

where some of the *batches* are apparently out of order relative to the key on which the query was ordered. Batches are run asynchronously and their order *relative to one another* is not guaranteed.

Comment: But we can be sure that inside all chunks we will get right order, correct?